# Removing done button in media picker

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mpmediapickercontroller

In my app I am using media picker when I click on a button media picker will appear. After selecting the required song I have to press done button to dismiss that picker view.
Instead of that can I have a any chance to dismiss picker view after selecting song without pressing done button?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative , You can use `allowsPickingMultipleItems` property. Set it to `NO`.

Comment: but will this dismiss the picker automatically or you will still have to press the done button..?

Comment: ya..but i dont want that done button to appear , i just want navigation bar with title only

Comment: @ganeshmanoj have you tried.. [mediaPicker.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];

Comment: thanx bro just now i used it..and..got it

Comment: after using this option i dont have option Add All songs  if i kept yes for that property i have that option and also done button

Comment: @ganeshmanoj: what you want ? How picker gets know that you are done with your choice ? Either you have to click on Done button or make it single selection...

Answer (score 0):

I guess the idea behind not having automatic disappearance of imagePicker from Apple is that Apple wants its users to make a different choice if something is selected by mistake. And mistakes happen quite offen as devices are touch based and accidental touches are quite frequent.

I don't have solution for your question but thought I should share my reasoning with others and seek their opinion on this.. :|

Comment: i think we can hide navigation bar but how get that done function after selecting song